# mysql query error: Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..5: 7

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

wrote a script that connects to a MySQL database and it works fine just a specific query line does not work and I feel like I have tried everything

I also created a table using this code and it worked fine with no errors

the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
RangeError (byteOffset): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..5: 7
#0      _ByteDataView.getUint16 (dart:typed_data-patch/typed_data_patch.dart:4824:7)
#1      Buffer.readUint16 (package:mysql1/src/buffer.dart:240:24)
#2      new PrepareOkPacket (package:mysql1/src/prepared_statements/prepare_ok_packet.dart:20:30)
#3      Handler.checkResponse (package:mysql1/src/handlers/handler.dart:68:24)
#4      PrepareHandler.processResponse (package:mysql1/src/prepared_statements/prepare_handler.dart:45:18)
#5      ReqRespConnection._handleData (package:mysql1/src/single_connection.dart:355:32)
#6      ReqRespConnection._handleHeader (package:mysql1/src/single_connection.dart:324:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ReqRespConnection._readPacket (package:mysql1/src/single_connection.dart:309:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

the code:

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

Future main() async {
    final conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        db: 'db',
        password: 'password'));


     var result = await conn.query(
        'INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ['name', 'password', 'email']);

}
```

Comment: This looks like a compatibility problem between the `mysql1.dart` library and the server. The server is sending a valuie back that the library doesn't understand.

Comment: The issue is with that Imported Dart .. so maybe you need to post the code from your include file so we can take a look at it.